# ASP.NET MVC paging large volumes of data using LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, pagination, large-data

I have large volumes of data (50000 rows), I want to display my data in a table.

Since the large volumes of data, I want to create custom pagination (for example at application startup display 10 record then when the user click page 2 another 10 records loaded from database and displayed).

Any ideas? or best practices to create this pagination and research?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your `pageNumber` and `pageSize` to the server side logic and get only a number of records from `DB`.

```
var customers = dbContext.Customers.FindAll().Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageNumber).ToList();
```

And `pageNumber` should be always greater than 0.

Comment: Thank you @Sunny

I follow the instructions on the tuto you mention it

I start the application, when I launch the index view I get an error of **Exceeding the waiting period**

Even I modified the web config to add <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/> and always the same error.
If you have any idea please help me.
Thanks in advane

Answer (score 0):

It's a very easy stuff...go through below link. If you have customer data then use the following type logic

```
 double pageCount = (double)((decimal)entities.Customers.Count() / Convert.ToDecimal(maxRows));
            customerModel.PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(pageCount);
```

Use the following link for more detail

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Server-Side-Paging-using-Entity-Framework-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: Thank you @Dnyaneshwar123489
I follow theses instructions but whene  I launch the index view I get an error of “Exceeding the waiting period” 
Even I modified the web config to add <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/> and always the same error.
If you have any idea please help me.
Thanks in advane